# Make Debian bleeding edge

Tags: debian, package-management

Debian is great and all but there is a huge problem: outdated packages. I get the whole stability thing, but I really want to use newer packages on Debian. I tried Sid, yet not even that has the most up-to-date packages. I am looking for a way to make Debian as bleeding edge as possible. Maybe there's a Debian-based distro that does that, or some 3rd party repos that offer newer packages? Please tell me if there's anything like that

Comment: Debian is not built for that. You might want to try a [`rolling release distribution`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_release).

Comment: Are the packages outdated or just extremely reliable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much as I love Debian, it isn’t the right distribution for you if you’re after a distribution that’s “as bleeding edge as possible”. Even Sid, as you say, basically because it’s not a distribution itself, but the “place” where the future release of Debian is developed; as a result of that:

- when the next version of Debian is frozen (which is currently the case, for Debian 11), package uploads to Sid are supposed to provide fixes or issues in the frozen release, so new upstream releases are no longer uploaded there (you can find some in experimental, but not all);
- many of the larger packages are constantly maintained with an eye on the next release, so for example new versions of the C library, the kernel, GCC etc. might not be uploaded to Sid as quickly as you’d like or expect.

Other packages can lag behind upstream due to lack of maintenance; in such cases, the fix is ideally to get involved with Debian’s development and help update them. But that doesn’t make up for the above if you really want a distribution with GCC 12, glibc 2.33, and version 5.13-rc6 of the kernel.

Ubuntu provides some packages in newer versions, and its six-month release cadence might be more appropriate for you, but the vast majority of its packages come from Debian and aren’t newer than the versions in Sid. I’m not aware of any other Debian derivative with newer packages of its own (*i.e.* not from Ubuntu).

Comment: Experimental isn’t a distribution. You can’t “run” experimental. And as I said, “you can find some in experimental, but not all” — currently, there’s no newer kernel in experimental, for example.

Comment: OK, so I take it you missed the fact that I mentioned experimental in my answer then ;-).

Comment: I just though `experimental` deserved a bit more attention than that ;-). I deleted the other answer and the comment, I hope that settles it.

Comment: Oh I didn’t necessarily expect you to delete your answer. My worry with giving experimental more attention is that [it really isn’t intended for general consumption](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianExperimental). When Debian isn’t frozen prior to a release, it’s the testing ground for things which are liable to break, and it shouldn’t be used without a lot of awareness.

Answer (score 0):

You could run Debian stable with backports enabled and -if aware of the possible caveats- prioritized:

For Debian Buster, add this line into your apt sources:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-backports main contrib non-free
```

And make it the preferred source by creating an apt policy file, e.g. `/etc/apt/preferences.d/99-prefer-backports` with these contents:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=buster-backports
Pin-Priority: 600
```

Now run this command to update your system:

```
apt-get update && apt-get clean && apt-get upgrade && apt-get clean && \
apt-get autoremove --purge && apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get clean && \
apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Result: Much newer drivers, firmwares, kernels, and everything that comes trickling back down into stable.

Comments from @StephenKitt:

"You don’t need a wholesale “upgrade” to backports to get new laptops working, a more targeted approach works just fine", also As documented on the backports site, “It is therefore recommended to only select single backported packages that fit your needs, and not use all available backports.”

The *targeted approach* he mentions above means:

Do not assign a priority to backports, instead install needed packages from backports on a package-by-package basis, using e.g.

`apt-get install -t buster-backports linux-image-amd64`

The "caveat" here is, that you need to know exactly which packages need to be upgraded.

Comment: No, no, no, you shouldn’t ever pin backports higher than the default — the packages it contains aren’t tested together. Backports should only be used to pick individual packages as necessary.

Comment: As documented on the [backports site](https://backports.debian.org/), “It is therefore recommended to only select single backported packages that fit your needs, and not use all available backports.”

Comment: @StephenKitt The OP asked what was possible. And the above works fairly reliably on Raspian, Armbian, Debian, and other Debian-Derivatives. Since years. Only minor little issues.

Comment: How many people does it work reliably for? Are you speaking for yourself, or do you have data from many other people? My main issue is that you’re encouraging something which the backports maintainers (and backports contributors including myself) explicitly discourage, without mentioning the caveats.

Comment: @StephenKitt It works reliably on quite a number ob HW/SW combinations in my (and others) daily usage. And it's often the **only** way to get new laptops to work with all features. But, you're right, i should have mentioned, that once every 15th moon or so, you may have to manually fix something. Or would you like to word something in yourself? Oh, and if possible, could you help advance the next NetworkManager version into Backports? And/Or enable 802.11s meshing in wpa_supplicant?

Comment: You don’t need a wholesale “upgrade” to backports to get new laptops working, a more targeted approach works just fine ;-). I’ll leave the phrasing up to you; if you left it to me I’d be liable to rewrite the post to only suggest `-t buster-backports` as appropriate...

Comment: @StephenKitt I'm aware of the targeted approach. I used it the first few years of backports. But difficult over the phone. Since then I've have many calls from people with new laptops attempting to install Debian stable and failing. Nearly all of them were "solved" with 'USB-tether with your android, use expert install, select "non-free", defaults for everything else, reboot, add Backports, install all firmwares, upgrade, reboot'. Most of those people never again mention problems with their gear. I'll edit a "warning" into the post and mention the targeted approach

Comment: Regarding an NM backport, [one was requested last summer](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=968478); I see the build is straightforward, I’ll look into it. Your users might be interested in [installation images with firmware on-board](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current/), it would avoid the initial “expert” step. Thanks for providing support to users and helping them get up and running, it’s much appreciated!

Comment: (And I imagine you’re aware of the non-free images, and that the main problem is that they aren’t easy to guide people to over the phone either.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124671/discussion-between-alex-stragies-and-stephen-kitt).